# Facebook authentication with extended permission request

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-app-engine, facebook

I'm wondering which authentication method to use if i need extended permissions (e.g. if i want to use the users photos in my application). The methods are either the single-sign on using JavaScript SDK or by using the OAuth 2.0 protocol. Both methods are explained here: [Authentication - Facebook developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). The JS SDK would be easiest but haven't found a solution yet.

The application will utilize the Google Appengine with Django environment.

Comment: What is your question? Can you be specific please?

Comment: Which method is the best/most convenient if i want to implement Facebook authentication with extended permissions using Google app engine and Django? At the moment i've been checking out this <a href="http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/tree/master/examples/oauth/">example</a> but had some trouble implementing it with Django...

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the entire Facebook API is undergoing changes.
I would suggest you use the OAuth API - it appears as this is the direction they will adopt.

A word of caution - the "official" documentation in the page you mentioned are not complete at best and some of the options are still buggy (try setting display=wap with scope=... you will get an error).

Check out the [Facebook developer forum](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=59646) on the issue I stated above.
I believe you can find answers to other Facebook related issues there.